# How to switch to "Graph View" in IDA Pro while debugging with WinDbg inside a system DLL?

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, debuggers

While debugging inside a loaded `exe` process (using `IDA Pro` as a disassembler, and `WinDbg` as a debugger) I can right click the code view and select `Graph view`:

[image]

That will switch it to this nice code-flow view that is much easier to read:

[image]

But if I step into a system DLL (in this case `mshtml.dll`) I can't seem to get that same `Graph view` command, and instead I get this generic view:

[image]

So I was wondering, if there's a way to enable `Graph view` for a system DLL as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IDA can only display functions in graph mode, so in order to see that code as a graph, you must:

#### Find the start of the function

Search for a prologue, such as `push ebp`, `mov ebp, esp`<sup>1</sup>, and find the start of the function. If it gets hard, you can always load debug symbols<sup>2</sup> and find the start like that.

1: Actually, most Microsoft DLLs are compiled with the hotpatch option, which means that the prologue is prefixed with `mov edi, edi` ([here's why](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583)), so searching for that instruction should be very easy.

2: In the WinDbg command line, write `.symfix` to fix the symbols path and `.reload /f mshtml.dll` to reload the symbols for that module. Alternatively, go to `Debugger` -> `Debugger windows` -> `Modules list`, find `mshtml.dll` in the window, right-click it and choose "Load debug symbols". Then, simply use the `Functions` window or the status bar to find the start of the function.

#### Make it a function

Put the cursor at the start, and press <kbd>P</kbd>. Now press <kbd>Space</kbd> and you'll be in graph mode!

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I didn't realize is that it takes `Ida Pro` some time before "Graph view" option becomes available, i.e. it evidently needs to scan the module after symbols are loaded. After that it will work just fine!